# Prove that points lie on the same circle

Tags: geometry

> Let Circles $C_1$ (center $O_1$) and $C_2$ (center $O_2$) intersect at points $P$ and $Q$.  $O_2$ is outside of $C_1$, $O_1$ is outside of $C_2$.  Let $O_1P$ intersect $C_2$ at $R$ and $O_2P$ intersect $C_1$ at $S$.  Prove that the points $R$, $S$, $O_1$, $O_2$ lie on the same circle.

Proving that the quadrilateral $O_1SRO_2$ can be inscribed in a circle seems like the next logical step, but I am having difficulties.

Comment: Explaining your difficulties may get you some answers.

Comment: Apologies as I'm fairly new to this website.  I have my vertical angles and I believe my next step is to move on to proving some similar triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have

$$\angle O_1 PS =\angle O_2 PR$$

Because they are vertically opposite angles.

Then consider what type of triangles are $\triangle O_1 PS$

Comment: $\triangle O_1 PS$ similar to $\triangle O_2 PR$?

Comment: @tlallstar6 Yes, and you would have more information about the angles. Can you relate them?

Comment: $\angle O_1 SP$ = $\angle O_2 RP$  

$\angle SO_1 P$ = $\angle RO_2 P$


$\angle SPR$ = $\angle O_1 PO_2$

$\triangle SPR$ similar to $\triangle O_1 PO_2$

$\angle PO_1 O_2$ = $\angle PSR$  

$\angle PO_2 O_1$ = $\angle PRS$

Are these similar triangles due to SAS? I'm very poor at similar triangles.

Comment: @tlallstar6 Actually you don't need to prove for similar triangles. You just need to show that some angles are equal in order to prove that the points are concyclic. (Think about what type of triangles they are)

Comment: Isosceles triangles as each of the two triangle has two equal sides (radius of the circle it is in)

Comment: @tlallstar6 Yes, so you know that some angles are equal. Does that satisfy the condition for concyclic points?

Comment: $$\angle SO_1 R= \angle SO_2 R$$ which satisfies the condition to have concyclic verticies.  This is also only true if opposite angles are supplementary....which means the quadrilateral can be inscribed and the points discussed all lie on the same circle.

Comment: @tlallstar6 Yes exactly. It is the converse of "angles in the same segment". Because the two angles would be equal if and only if they are in the same circle